# SQL Server 2008 R2 - store top result and use in SSRS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables

I have a SSRS Report that displays the total number of days lapsed since a complaint was received. This SQL Query is the difference between today's date and date of the last received complaint.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, MAX(complaints.ComplaintReceived1Date),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as total 
FROM complaints WITH (nolock)
```

If for example this is set to 30 (days) and then a complaint is received in my SSRS report I would like to display 30 as previous number of days with no complaint record. Is there a way to store previous results and recall this data? Maybe a temp table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already storing it in the table referenced by your SQL query.

I would just retrieve it from there:

```
; with previouscomplaint as (

select 
complaintreceived1date,
RN = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by complaintreceived1dateorder by complaintreceived1date desc))


select datediff(day,complaintreceived1date,current_timestamp) as previoustotal from previouscomplaint where RN=2
```

If you want the dates between the two rows, make the second statement:

```
select datediff(day, (select complaintreceived1date from previouscomplaint where rn = 2),(select complaintreceived1date from previouscomplaint where rn = 1)) as previoustotal
```

This was not tested, but should work.

Comment: Hi thanks @Eric Hauenstein for your comment - I don't store this in a table I only have a 'complaint received' table not a 'previous complaint' table. i'm simply finding the number of days between last complaint received and todays date. for example its currently set to 30 but and before this it was set to 40 so in SSRS I would like to show on my report "record number of days with no complaint = 40" not sure how this can be achieved.

Comment: You are selecting from the "Complaints" table, right?  It should contain a list of all the complaints you have received, correct?  If so, then the code I posted should retrieve the complaint *prior* to the current complaint, which I think is what you want.

Comment: thanks @Eric Hauenstein this is exactly what I was after